# No @javax.jws.WebService found

Tags: java, maven, soap, jax-ws

Estoy tratando de generar un archivo wsdl a partir de un modelo e interfaz con anotaciones

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
```

No hay forma, me dice que no encuentra la clase o

> No @javax.jws.WebService found

He probado con el comando `wsgen` y el plugin de maven

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
```

La ruta de la clase es correcta.

Ya intenté con Java versiones 8 y 11

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java usa? Hace poco cambiaron los imports de JavaEE para que en vez de iniciar con `javax` en el import dijera `jakarta`

Comment: estoy probando con la 8 y la 11